# Check point in two polygon (code improvement)

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, geopandas

Question: I want to improve my code to get `ID` of cars **started** and **ended** between given 2 zones of the city.

I have:

1. `.csv file containing city zones like this:

   ```
   borders =

   zone longitude latitude multi
   12   3.5248    22.0952  MULTIPOLYGON(((3.4991688909 22.1096707778,3.4992650150 22.1094740107, ... ,3.4992922409 22.1094203597,3.4995744041 22.1087939694,3.4997139945 22.1081206986)))
   14   3.5139    22.111   MULTIPOLYGON(((12.4991688909 22.1096707778,3.4992650150 22.1094740107, ... ,32.4992922409 22.1094203597,3.4995744041 32.1087939694,3.4997139945 22.1081206986)))
   ...
   800  3.5273    22.1019  MULTIPOLYGON(((4.4991688909 15.1096707778,3.4992650150 22.1094740107, ... ,4.4992922409 75.1094203597,3.4995744041 22.1087939694,3.4997139945 22.1081206986)))
   ```

Thus, I want to check if my

2. .csv file containing taxi cars's data:

   ```
   data = 

   ID      latitude longitude epoch        day_of_week

   e35f6   11.9125  3.7432    8765456787    Sunday
   e35f6   11.9125  3.7432    4567876545    Sunday
   ...
   fhg3g   23.9125  5.7432    2345434554    Sunday
   ```

Thus, I want to check if my car `ID` starting the  trip in `zone` 12 and end in `zone` 14 (but I want to check every zone)

What I did so far:

- I manually go to the `border` file, choose 2 rows, creating new csv file, entering geo data of multipolygon manually and converting t to POINT (geopandas)
- The doing the same woth `data`

Then

- Choosing forst point and last point of each ID in `data`
- theb cheking if my first point within the first zone and last foint within the second zone.
- Then merging new data frames to check intersected `ID`s to see if same car started and ended at a zone.

But it t is very time consuming process. Looking for an improvement. 
Here is my code:

```
df_first = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id_easy'], keep='first') # removed duplicates
df_last = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id_easy'], keep='last') # removed duplicates

crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}
geometry_first = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df_first.longitude,df_first.latitude)]
df_first = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_first,crs=crs,geometry=geometry_first)

geometry_last = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df_last.longitude,df_last.latitude)]
df_last = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_last,crs=crs,geometry=geometry_last)

border_1 = pd.read_csv("D:/anaconda path/PTV/1) Data preparation/between zones/zone1.csv")

geometry_1 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(border_1.longitude,border_1.latitude)]
border_1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(border_1,crs=crs,geometry=geometry_1)

border_2 = pd.read_csv("D:/anaconda path/PTV/1) Data preparation/between zones/zone2.csv")

geometry_2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(border_2.longitude,border_2.latitude)]
border_2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(border_2,crs=crs,geometry=geometry_2)

turin_final_1 = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border_1.geometry])
first = df_first[df_first.geometry.within(turin_final_1)]

turin_final_2 = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border_2.geometry])
last = df_last[df_last.geometry.within(turin_final_2)]
first.epoch = pd.to_datetime(first.epoch,unit = 's')

first.index = pd.to_datetime(first.epoch)
last.index = pd.to_datetime(last.epoch)

first1 = first.between_time('0:00', '1:00')
last1 = last.between_time('0:00', '1:00') #till to 24

first1.to_csv(r'D:\anaconda path\PTV\1) Data preparation\between zones\df1\Saturday1_first1.csv',index=False)
last1.to_csv(r'D:\anaconda path\PTV\1) Data preparation\between zones\df2\Saturday1_last1.csv',index=False) #till to 24

os.chdir("D:/anaconda path/PTV/1) Data preparation/between zones/df1")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

df1 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
df1.to_csv( "df1.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

os.chdir("D:/anaconda path/PTV/1) Data preparation/between zones/df2")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

df2 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
df2.to_csv( "df2.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

df1 = pd.read_csv("D:/anaconda path/PTV/1) Data preparation/between zones/df1/df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("D:/anaconda path/PTV/1) Data preparation/between zones/df2/df2.csv")

df3 = (pd.concat((df1[df1.id_easy.isin(df2.id_easy)],
            df2[df2.id_easy.isin(df1.id_easy)]),
           ignore_index=True)
    .sort_values('id_easy'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to assign the zone number to the starting point and to the end point of each car. Since you have polygon information on the shape of the city zones (multi column) in the borders data, I suggest you use this information for a spatial join on the starting/end points to see which zone a car starts/ends the journey. Here is my suggestion in more detail:

I'm assuming that you have already read the data in `border` and `data` and the that it is formatted correctly (i.e. each cell in the `multi` column of `border` contains a `Shapley.Multipolygon`). I'm also assuming that your zones are disjoint, i.e. no overlapping.

A `GeoDataFrame` needs a geometry column, as it can only recognise a column with this name as geometric information:

```
border['geometry'] = border['multi']
```

Now we also generate the geometric information for the points given in the car data in `df`:

```
df['geometry'] = df[['longitude', 'latitude']].apply(lambda x: Point(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
```

As you have done, let's now extract the start and end points:

```
df_first = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id_easy'], keep='first')
df_last = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id_easy'], keep='last')
```

Now we can do a spatial join to get zones of each starting and end point as desired:

```
df_first = gpd.sjoin(df_first, shp.loc[:, ['geometry', 'zone']], how='left', op='within')
df_last = gpd.sjoin(df_last, shp.loc[:, ['geometry', 'zone']], how='left', op='within')
```

That's it. Now you have the information on the zones in the `zone` column for each point.